# How to transmit a SOAP request with MTOM using php

Tags: php, curl, soap, mtom

I have searched the internet for this answer. I am giving extra details in case someone on SO has encountered this, since we are getting little to no help from those managing the soap server. Here's the challenge:

A request requires a SOAP+WSDL with an MTOM attachment. The example they give is as follows:

```
    <ser:COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission>
     <PayloadType>X12_270_Request_005010X279A1</PayloadType>
     <ProcessingMode>Batch</ProcessingMode>
     <PayloadID>e34d8fae-5dec-08d0-a555-00a0c55e5da1</PayloadID>
     <PayloadLength>518</PayloadLength>
     <TimeStamp>2015-02-01T18:42:30Z</TimeStamp>
     <SenderID>110000000Z</SenderID>
     <ReceiverID>MMXX</ReceiverID>
     <CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</CORERuleVersion>
     <CheckSum>D165797749C4909B582D2167B2195C4A25CDD584</CheckSum>
     <Payload>cid:251081255115</Payload>
   </ser:COREEnvelopeBatchSubmission>
```

The Payload (cid:251081255115) must be send as an W3C Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) encapsulated MIME part.

It appears most folks can do this in java. We need to do this (POST a SOAP request with MTOM attachment of an .edi file) using cURL and PHP. Has anyone ever done this successfully? Can you provide an example?